# Raspberry 3B+ Wifi not works anymore also with new OS/Sdcard.. broken chip? Please help!

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, driver, update

EDIT:
On suggestions of @milliways I'm editing the question since he says that all the stuff I posted is irrelevant, and I have to "start fresh".
I installed again a new fresh image of Raspberry Os Lite 32bit and just after the first boot and following all the post-install config (locale, username, password, wifi country, wifi ssid and password), still no wifi.
I issued the commands suggested and this is the result:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -irdc
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

and

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /sys/class/net/
eth0  lo  wlan0
```

then

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli list_networks
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
```

and trying to set up wlan in raspi-config says "**no wireless interfaces found**"

Tried also

```
**sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID**
```

and the result is

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Connection timed out
```

I think I will surrender and send it in the trash can...

---------------- ORIGINAL POST ------------------------------

First of all let me say "I'm sorry" because this will be a quite long post, since I will try to include all the tests, commands and replies from the system that I tried before writing here, hoping that someone will catch up what I'm missing..
Please also note that I'm not a linux expert, I' not a total newbie but just a bit more, I dont know how to install a driver or how to check somethings, and all I did in my tests is done after searching on the web

So this is the story:

I have an old raspberry 3b+ that is working without issues from years.
In the last months I used it to control my 3d Printer with the firmware "klipper" and MainsaillOS (that should be based on debian if I'm not wrong) and all worked fine until yesterday.

During an ssh session I issued an "apt-get update" command and then powered itt off. Now I dont know if it was just a bad coincidence, but when I powered it up again after a couple of hours, Wifi not worked anymore. There was no way to connect.

First thing I did, thinking to a sd-card corruption, I restored a full img backup on a new sd card, and still no wifi.
So I tried to write a **fresh new RasberryPi OS Lite (32bit)** on a **brand new microsd** using Pi Imager, and still no wifi. I also added the wpa_supplicant.conf file, no luck. I tried to reboot my router, nothing.

I tried to install **ubuntu server 23.04 32bit** : same issue.
So **I reflashed the Pi Os Lite 32bit**, connected the Pi to my monitor via hdmi and tried to investigate better.

**All the commands and replies here below, are done on this new, fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS Lite 32 bit, on the first login, without issuing any update or upgrage, so there sould be something wrong that is "embedded" in the chip (firmware?) or a broken chip.**

First thing I noticed was that during the boot there are no errors except the following rows:
***[FAILED] Failed to start Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
See 'systemctl statushciuart.service' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependecy failed fpr Raspberry Pi bluetooth helper.
Starting bluetooth service...***
[OK] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status
and so on....

So I started searching on the web for solutions.. I tried a lot of things.. but nothing worked, So i'm here..
.
I'm adding all the stuff I tried and the response in the following lines.
Please some one could help me to have back my wifi or say me if it's broken?
I can connect via ethernet with no issues at all.

***iwconfig***

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enxb827ebacb53e  no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

***ifconfig***

```
   enxb827ebacb53e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.1.25  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
            inet6 fe80::bf27:a22f:c7ba:9c29  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether b8:27:eb:ac:b5:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 3700  bytes 454487 (443.8 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 2218  bytes 466896 (455.9 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
            inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
            inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
            loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
            RX packets 10  bytes 1570 (1.5 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 10  bytes 1570 (1.5 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

***rfkill list***

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

***iw wlan0 scan***

```
   command failed: Network is down (-100)
```

Tried to set Power Management off..

***sudo ifconfig wlan0 set power off***

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
```

***Tried to power down (no error) and up (error)***

```
pi@raspi2:~ $ sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
pi@raspi2:~ $ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
```

***sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf***

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Input/output error
nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

***Firmware version (I updated it, but still nothing)***

```
sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version
Apr 25 2023 18:32:05
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version d7f9c2b4ef7e4a8c0b04374a879ce89d7a948453 (clean) (release) (start)
```

***sudo lshw -C network***

```
  *-usb:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC)
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.1
       logical name: enxb827ebacb53e
       version: 2.00
       serial: b8:27:eb:ac:b5:3e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=smsc95xx driverversion=6.1.31-v7+ duplex=full firmware=smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.1.25 link=yes maxpower=2mA multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: b8:27:eb:f9:e0:6b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.98 firmware=01-8e14b897 ip=127.0.0.1 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

***sudo ip link set wlan0 up***

```
RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error
```

***sudo iwlist wlan0 scan wlan0***

```
Interface doesn't support scanning :
Network is down
```

And lastly I want also to add the **DMESG** because there are some "intersting lines" that maybe point in some issue... ***There are A LOT of errors in the end*** about some driver/device/service (I dont understand linux to this point), you can look starting from 10 second...

here it is...

```
[   10.153993] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   10.154161] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   10.154177] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.154209] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.154230] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.154263] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.278788] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   10.278825] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   10.278950] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   10.279254] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   10.280525] hci_uart_bcm serial0-0: supply vbat not found, using dummy regulator
[   10.280844] hci_uart_bcm serial0-0: supply vddio not found, using dummy regulator
[   10.398503] uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[   10.450989] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[   10.481627] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 enxb827ebacb53e: renamed from eth0
[   10.655001] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
**[   10.675284] cfg80211: loaded regulatory.db is malformed or signature is missing/invalid**
[   10.876781] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x1541a9a6
[   10.907365] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   10.908071] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   11.186275] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Jul 19 2021 03:24:18 version 7.45.98 (TOB) (56df937 CY) FWID 01-8e14b897
[   11.482705] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x30
[   11.496537] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
[   11.510526] Registered IR keymap rc-cec
[   11.510812] rc rc0: vc4-hdmi as /devices/platform/soc/3f902000.hdmi/rc/rc0
[   11.511081] input: vc4-hdmi as /devices/platform/soc/3f902000.hdmi/rc/rc0/input4
[   11.533980] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f902000.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
[   11.534628] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f004000.txp (ops vc4_txp_ops [vc4])
[   11.550242] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f206000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   11.550741] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f207000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   11.551160] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f807000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   11.551523] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3fc00000.v3d (ops vc4_v3d_ops [vc4])
[   11.691285] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for soc:gpu on minor 0
[   11.786383] vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm] The core clock cannot reach frequencies high enough to support 4k @ 60Hz.
[   11.786436] vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm] Please change your config.txt file to add hdmi_enable_4kp60.
[   11.855144] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[   11.901938] vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm] fb0: vc4drmfb frame buffer device
[   12.005133] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   12.282668] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   12.352145] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 enxb827ebacb53e: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   12.354931] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 enxb827ebacb53e: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[   12.355033] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enxb827ebacb53e: link becomes ready
**[   12.558225] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc18 tx timeout
[   12.769172] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   12.769309] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   12.769697] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   12.770143] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   12.770462] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   12.770499] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   12.773787] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   12.773835] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: Country code iovar returned err = -110
[   12.962426] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   12.962567] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   12.962973] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   12.963406] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   12.963905] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   12.963937] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   12.970254] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   12.970296] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: Country code iovar returned err = -110
[   13.201397] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.201519] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.201900] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.202317] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.202612] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.202636] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.202664] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.202686] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_channel: chanspec failed (-110)
[   13.206846] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.206968] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.207386] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.207746] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.208056] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.208177] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.208203] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_channel: chanspec failed (-110)
[   13.208243] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.213098] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.213217] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.213611] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.213983] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.214371] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.214398] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.214435] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.214471] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_channel: chanspec failed (-110)
[   13.219011] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.219145] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.219545] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.219970] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.220390] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.220420] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.226254] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.226293] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_channel: chanspec failed (-110)
[   13.236397] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.236510] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.236816] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.237106] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.237359] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.237381] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.237412] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.237435] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_channel: chanspec failed (-110)
[   13.241479] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.241599] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.241924] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.242226] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.242484] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.242510] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.244172] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.248291] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.248414] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.248734] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.249105] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.249389] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.249418] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.254449] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.254561] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.254840] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.255114] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.255349] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.255371] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.255408] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_dongle_scantime: Scan assoc time error (-110)
[   13.258983] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.259095] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.259685] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.260024] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.260360] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.260387] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.260440] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_netdev_open: failed to bring up cfg80211
[   13.264702] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.264811] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.265095] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.265381] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.265617] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.265640] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.265684] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.265707] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_channel: chanspec failed (-110)
[   13.268873] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.268992] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.269305] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.269608] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.269846] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.269869] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.269911] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.269936] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_tx_power: error (-110)
[   13.364637] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.364749] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.365128] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.365426] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.365688] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.365709] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.365736] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[   13.369032] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.369139] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.369458] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.369757] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.370071] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.370093] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.373955] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.374068] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.374364] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.374650] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.374890] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.374913] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.374943] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_dongle_scantime: Scan assoc time error (-110)
[   13.379192] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_sleep: error while changing bus sleep state -110
[   13.379308] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.379649] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.379958] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
[   13.380233] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-110
[   13.380256] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
[   13.380290] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_netdev_open: failed to bring up cfg80211
[   13.645227] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.645259] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.645289] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.299858] ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.enxb827ebacb53e.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.enxb827ebacb53e.retrans_time_ms instead
[   20.958109] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: failed to write update baudrate (-110)
[   20.958134] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set baudrate
[   23.038129] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[   31.198121] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)**
```

Thanks for any help to not throw my 3b+ in the trash...

Comment: `I issued an "apt-get update" command and then powered itt off` - did you wait for the update for finish?

Comment: First you haven't said what OS you were using when you posted results. Second DON'T ever use apt-get use apt.  You have mixed lots of obsolete commands and have done something you haven't disclosed because you show enx device. Try a standard Raspberry Pi OS installation and don't enter any non standard settings. There is no wpa_supplicant.txt

Comment: @JaromandaX of course, yes.

Comment: @Milliways as I wrote, I experienced this on Raspberry Pi OS Lite 32 Bit. I tried also Ubuntu Server 23.04 32 Bit, with same results. Than reinstalled Raspberry Pi OS Lite 32 Bit (since it's the OS that I'm using and I will have to use) and did all the tests. So I already tried a new, fresh os install and just after the first boot, without issuing any command, I have the same result: infact all the commands that I wrote here are done on a fresh install! (sorry for the .txt, is .conf...)

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS is ambiguous. You couldn't have the same "results" because some of the commands you used required software not in standard installation. It is impossible to diagnose when people claim to have used multiple OS. WiFi won't work unless you complete post installation configuration e.g. setting locale etc.

Comment: Since the wifi problem "survive" between different OS images, I think there is something wrong that is "embedded" in the chip at low-level (firmware?) or the chip itself is broken, because if it was a configuration issue, it should disappear as soon I will insert a new sd card with a fresh new OS on it, right?

Comment: @Milliways only thing I did that I didnt wrote , was to install lshw and lastly gone in raspi-config and activate network descriptive devices (I dont recall the config option

Comment: @Milliways Anyway justo to be sure, I just tried again... I didnt use the Rasberry PI Imager this time: downloaded the RaspberryPi OS Lite 32 bit from raspberry site and flashed it with Balena Etcher. at the first boot it asked to choouse country and keyboard layout and to create usename and passoword. Then says me that wifi was off due to rfkill and to activate it I will have to go in raspi-config to choose a country. I did it, going in system setting, wireless lan, choosed my country, entered my SSID and password, exit fro raspi-config and rebooted.  well.. same issue. no wifi.

Comment: @Milliways and please also note that in the previous tests I didnt the post-install configuration since I used Raspberry Imager for the flashing, and it gives you the possibility to add the configurations needed (locale, usenrame and password, ssh activation, wifi ssid and paswword) directly in the flash process.

Comment: If you want help and have installed a fresh OS all the stuff you posted is irrelevant start by posting some systematic diagnostics. `lsb_release -irdc`, `ls /sys/class/net/` which will show which interfaces exist. You also need to explain any commands you entered. DO NOT post detail in Comments EDIT your Question

Comment: @Milliways I edited my original post and added the results of the commands there.

Comment: `ls /sys/class/net/` shows that you have a WiFi interface `wlan0`. You could try configuring it in `raspi-config / System Options / Wireless LAN` or try `wpa_cli list_networks`

Comment: @Milliways `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli list_networks
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory` and going in raspi-config says "no wireless interfaces found"

Comment: One last attempt to help. First **DO NOT post detail in Comments** (and you could delete those you have already added to make things clearer). What does the command `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID` show?

Comment: @Milliways tried your suggestion but didnt worked out differently than bevore (see the edited post for details). I thing that there is something really really strange happening here, but I'm not too much deep in linux to understand what is the real issue. One thing that still makes me thinkering is that I can try any different OS compatible with the PI, the result is still the same, so it's not a "software" issue, it's a firmware issue (or hardware.. maybe...)

Comment: @Milliways ok something really weird happened... the PI is now connected in WIFI to my router... the wifi works now. After last command I tried to issue an iwconfig.. and it appeared connected to my network....  Really, i didnt changed anything, and the board itself was disconnected from power for more than 24 hours, from the last time that I issued the command you gave me yesterday... Really dont know how it's possible....

Comment: LOL this is crazy. rebooted and now.. no wifi and same errors as before.. phisically I didnt touched the board (so could not be an issue of bad soldering contacts and so on...). Ok, I think I will take the board and put it in a closet, I will use it again when I will need for some project where I dont need wifi. I wasted three days on this, I think it's enough.